# Electromagnetic field to cool a substance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation, freezing

I saw somewhere that an electromagnetic field would cause a substance to let off thermal energy, ultimately resulting in the substance to cool really quickly.

If this is possible, does the strength of the magnetic field correlate with the rate of cooling?  What are the physics behind this phenomena?

Comment: watch the video it will help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAUrQG91OuU

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of the [magnetocalorific effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration). When you put a paramagnetic material into a magnetic field the field aligns the magnetic dipoles within your material. This releases energy and heats up the material slightly.

If you let the material coll back down to ambient temperature then remove it from the magnetic field the dipoles return to a random configuration. This absorbs energy, so the material cools down slightly.

Comment: The question is about a "electromagnetic" action. I assume that he read about thermal emission and does not know what electromagnetic means. Maybe he read of magnetic cooling and does not know ....